# Macro to update table in Excel via SQL query worked prior to 360 upgrade, now gives error

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that, among other things, writes a SQL query from various input cells, runs the query, and updates data. The VBA in the back-end worked fine, but now that I've upgraded to Office 360 I get:

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.

Here's the VBA:

```vb
Sub Paid()

Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = Worksheets("SQL").Range("L6")
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Paid").OLEDBConnection 'here is the line that errors out
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .CommandText = strSQL
End With

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Paid").Refresh

End Sub
```

I double-checked the SQL directly into SSMS and the query works fine; though I don't think the query's the issue, it's the line:

```vb
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Paid").OLEDBConnection
```

Has anyone run into this issue, know how to get the data to successfully refresh?

Comment: Does that connection still exist?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 - yes and no. With the migration to 360, it's now listed under queries, not connections. Not sure how to either change it back to a connection (or have the VBA reference it as a query and update it accordingly)